# converting matrix to std::vector

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, stl, stdvector

I have the following matrix:

```
unsigned wins[8][3] = { { 0, 1, 2 }, { 3, 4, 5 }, { 6, 7, 8 }, { 0, 3, 6 }, { 1, 4, 7 }, { 2, 5, 8 }, { 0, 4, 8 }, { 2, 4, 6 } };
```

how to convert it into a std::vector?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the two iterator constructor to instantiate a vector with a copy of of the data in `wins`:

```
unsigned* start = &wins[0][0];
std::vector<unsigned> vwins(start, start + (8 * 3));
```

This relies on pointer arithmetic, the fact that pointers are iterators, and the fact that 2D arrays are contiguous blocks, essentially 1D arrays with clever indexing.

Comment: You mean, `unsigned _wins[8][3] = { { 0, 1, 2 }, { 3, 4, 5 }, { 6, 7, 8 }, { 0, 3, 6 }, { 1, 4, 7 }, { 2, 5, 8 }, { 0, 4, 8 }, { 2, 4, 6 } }; std::vector<unsigned> wins (_wins, _wins + (8 * 3));` ?

Comment: `wins` decays to `unsigned(*)[3]`.

Comment: I am getting `error C2955: 'std::vector' : use of class template requires template argument list` at `std::vector vwins<unsigned>(wins, wins + (8 * 3));`

Comment: I am getting more errors: `if (board[vwins[i][0]] != 0 && board[vwins[i][0]] == board[vwins[i][1]] && board[vwins[i][0]] == board[vwins[i][2]]) return board[vwins[i][2]];` Expression must have a pointer-to-object type

Comment: @coderrio that is because you are indexing the vector as a 2D array. You asked for a vector. If you need a vector of vectors, you should ask for that. Perhaps you should clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't know whether you want a 2D vector or not, I'll handle the 2D case since juanchopanza handled the 1D case. :) If you're using C++11, then you can just do this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<vector<int>> wins = { { 0, 1, 2 }, { 3, 4, 5 }, { 6, 7, 8 }, { 0, 3, 6 }, { 1, 4, 7 }, { 2, 5, 8 }, { 0, 4, 8 }, { 2, 4, 6 } };
    for(vector<int> & row : wins) {
        for(int &col : row) {
            cout << col << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This example uses C++11 initializer lists to create an analogous structure, also called wins. I also wrote a little code to show how you could loop through it to print it out in a sensical order.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks. I switched to vectors in my tic tac toe game but its not working properly. I mean, it asks me whether i want to play 1st or second and then it says computer move and hangs. Here's the code: http://pastebin.com/R94RRbz4 Is there something that I am doing wrong?

Comment: Ha! I knew it was tic tac toe by the numbers in the array! :) I just wrote a tic tac toe game myself a few days ago... let me take a look...

Comment: Whatever problem you have is probably in your minimax code... I would recommend setting a maximum depth on the search and seeing if that helps.

Comment: What do you mean by maximum depth?

Comment: I was just saying to take care that `minimax` doesn't call itself too many times.